# Spring Actuator Status Down Due to Solr Dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I can see that result when I want to check health metrics of my application which has Spring Boot Actuator:

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "diskSpace": {
    "status": "UP",
    "total": 299055067136,
    "free": 246445404160,
    "threshold": 10485760
  }
}
```

I can also see `/metrics` results. I want to reach such information from another Spring application. This works for `/metrics`:

```
restTemplate.getForObject(metricsPath, HashMap.class);
```

When I try that for health:

```
restTemplate.getForObject(healthPath, String.class);
```

I get a general `503` error. I've debugged the system and realized that Spring throws an error due to my `Solr` dependency. It tries to make a ping request to `127.0.0.1`

My questions:

1) How it works when I don't use `restTemplate`?

2) How can I indicate what is `Solr` path for `SolrHealthIndicator`?

**PS:** I can verify that problem relates to Solr because when I add:

```
management:
  health:
    solr:
      enabled:  false
```

I can see `Status` is `UP` with `restTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug when spring moved Solr 4 to Solr 5.
See for updates [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8463)